# About $D(F,G)=\int(F(x)-G(x))^2w(x)dx$ and $D(F,G)=\int(F(x)-G(x))^2w(x)dF(x)$

Tags: distance

I learned that statistical distance between two 1-dim distributions F and G

$D_E(F,G)=\int(F(x)-G(x))^2dx$ is famous.

But what about $D(F,G)=\int(F(x)-G(x))^2w(x)dx$ or $D(F,G)=\int(F(x)-G(x))^2w(x)dF(x)$?

**What are their names?**

**From what aspects could we evaluate the selection of $w(x)$ and find the best?**

Answer (score 1):

Your $w$ is a weight in your distance, there is no optimum, it is simply a choice that one has to make. It will skew your distance to give more importance over $x$ with a large $w(x)$.

Here are some exemples:

- If you care more about large value of x, $w(x) = x$
- If you care more about the relative gap between your 2 distributions, $w(x) = G(x)^2$. So you would then have an integral over $\frac{(F(x)-G(x))^2}{G(x)^2}$

We can think about almost any weight you want depending how why and how you are using this distance